# PHP SimpleXML->addChild - unwanted empty namespace attribute

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml, addchild

I'm attempting to use SimpleXML's addChild method of the SimpleXMLElement (actually a SimpleXMLIterator which is a subclass of SimpleXMLElement) to add child elements.

My problem is that the source document contains a mixture of elements with namespaces and without. Here's a *simple* (no pun intended) example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ns1:a xmlns:ns1="http://www.abc.com">
</ns1:a>
```

The PHP code is:

```
$it = new SimpleXMLIterator ('./test.xml', 0, true);
$it->addChild('d', 'another!'); // adds new child element to parent's NS
$it->addChild('c', 'no namespace for me!', ''); // puts xmlns="" every time :(

//output xml in response:
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo $it->saveXML();
```

The problem - as the comment states - is that if I want to place a child element with no namespace inside of the parent element with a namespace, I get an empty XML namespace attribute every time (output of above PHP code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ns1:a xmlns:ns1="http://www.abc.com">
  <ns1:d>another!</ns1:d>
  <c xmlns="">no namespace for me!</c>
</ns1:a>
```

While both web browsers as well as XML parsers (e.g. Xerces) don't seem to mind this superfluous markup, I find it slightly annoying that I can't seem to tell it to stop doing this.

Anyone have a solution or am I over reacting?

:}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SimpleXML c needs a namespace. If you specify one, it gets an xmlns attribute because what you specified has not been declared before. If you don't specify a namespace for c, it inherits the namespace from the parent node. The only option here is `ns1`. (This happens to d.)

To prevent inhertance of the parent namespace **and** omit empty `xmlns` you'd need an namespace like `xmlns="http://example.com"` at the parent. Then `$it->addChild('c', 'no ns', 'http://example.com')` gives you `<c>no ns</c>`.

However you cannot inject additional namespaces e.g. with `addAttribute`. You have to manipulate the input file before it's parsed by SimpleXML. To me this seems even more ugly than removing all empty xmlns attributes from the output.

Comment: Rik, although it still requires me to have a namespace it appears that your solution is a good fit - especially if I'm dealing with HTML. Thanks for your prompt reply and answer, much appreciated. :D