# Why SimpleXMLElement prefixes all soap childs?

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I'm building a `SOAP` message for the first time and playing it with PHP.

The requirements are `SOAP` version `1.1` with **Style/Enconding: Document/Literal** pattern.

Using `SimpleXMLElement`:

```
    $soapEnv = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"></soap:Envelope>';
    $soapEnvElement = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . $soapEnv);
    $soapEnvElement->addChild('soap:Header');
    $bodyElement = $soapEnvElement->addChild('soap:Body');
    $bodyElement->addChild('node');
    echo $soapEnvElement->asXML();
```

**Expected output:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <node/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Actual output:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:node/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Question**

Why is this happening?

Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP SimpleXML->addChild - unwanted empty namespace attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672274/php-simplexml-addchild-unwanted-empty-namespace-attribute)

Comment: @spash58 , the link you provided does answer what AlexandreThebaldi asked, but it's worth keeping this question as a non-duplicate, because it is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

@splash58's comment does indeed answer your question.

The linked question has an answer that explains perfectly what is going on.

> For SimpleXML c needs a namespace. If you specify one, it gets an xmlns attribute because what you specified has not been declared before. If you don't specify a namespace for c, it inherits the namespace from the parent node. The only option here is ns1. (This happens to d.)
>
> To prevent inhertance of the parent namespace and omit empty xmlns you'd need an namespace like `xmlns="http://example.com"` at the parent. Then `$it->addChild('c', 'no ns', 'http://example.com')` gives you no ns.

Proof:

```
<?php

// Notice here that I added the extra namespace for http://example.com.
$soapEnv = '<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"></soap:Envelope>';
$soapEnvElement = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . $soapEnv);
$soapEnvElement->addChild('soap:Header');
$bodyElement = $soapEnvElement->addChild('soap:Body');
// Here I am applying the empty namespace so it doesn't inherit from the parent node.
$bodyElement->addChild('node', '', 'http://example.com');
echo $soapEnvElement->asXML();
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <node/>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: By the way, do you know how to add the `xmlns` attribute directly on `node` element when creating it? This would be a most appropriate behavior for my case. By default, PHP creates an empty `xmlns` that I can't fill it after.